# Spring-build-src maven dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm converting a project to maven and have found dependencies for every jar in the spring framework but the spring-build-src dependency.
Is this a necessary dependency and where could I find the dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's inside Spring Webflow (below the latest version, pick up the one you need)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency
```